# where is the popup settings in google chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a google chrome extension using the manifest v3, I read the manifest docs from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/#overview) but found that did not contains popup settings, in v2 of manifest, we could set up popup like this:

```
"browser_action" : {
    "default_icon" : {
      "19" : "/logo.png" ,
      "38" : "/logo.png"
    } ,
    "default_popup" : "/popup/index.html"
  } ,
```

how to set the default popup page in manifest v3 of google chrome extension?

Comment: Full error message, please

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ok, I suddenly found that the popup setting was moved to actions, it could be setting like this:

```
{
  "name": "Action Extension",
  ...
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {              // optional
      "16": "images/icon16.png",   // optional
      "24": "images/icon24.png",   // optional
      "32": "images/icon32.png"    // optional
    },
    "default_title": "Click Me",   // optional, shown in tooltip
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  // optional
  },
  ...
}
```

here is the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/).